# Indefinite integral of elliptic integrals

Tags: reference-request, closed-form, elliptic-integrals

Derivative of complete elliptic integrals, $E(k)$, [$K(k)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html), etc., are known. But, I don't know about their integrals.

I tried to evaluate the indefinite integral
$$\int_0^k K(k)dk\tag1$$
and ended up with
$$\int_0^{\arcsin k}\frac{k\phi\cos\phi}{\sqrt{k^2-\sin^2\phi}}d\phi\tag2$$

Is my calculation $(2)$ correct? Is there a closed-form of $(1)$?

Thanks.